# Hyperref links pointing to the same place (using thmtools and answers packages)

Tags: hyperref, thmtools, answers

At the end of each problem, I'd like to have the indication of the page number of the solution to that problem.

If I do something like this,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
notefont=\bfseries,
notebraces={}{}, 
headformat={\large\NUMBER.\NOTE},
headpunct={\vspace{\topsep}\newline},
spacebelow=40pt,
prefoothook={\hfill Solução: pág. \pageref{solucao:\Currentlabel}}
]{problemastyle}

\declaretheorem[style=problemastyle]{problema}

\usepackage{answers}

\Newassociation{solucao}{Sol}{solucoes}
\renewenvironment{Sol}[1]{\begin{trivlist}
 \item[\hskip\labelsep\textbf{#1.}] \label{solucao:#1} \ignorespaces}%
 {\end{trivlist}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{solucoes}

\begin{problema}[Primeiro problema]
 Problema 1.
 \begin{solucao}
   \lipsum
 \end{solucao}
\end{problema}

\begin{problema}[Segundo problema]
 Problema 2.
 \begin{solucao}
   \lipsum[1]
 \end{solucao}
\end{problema}

\begin{problema}[Terceiro problema]
 Problema 3.
 \begin{solucao}
   \lipsum[1]
 \end{solucao}
\end{problema}


\Closesolutionfile{solucoes}

\include{solucoes}

\end{document}
```

I get what I want, but the links on the page numbers are all pointing to the same place.

How can I correct this?

Comment: a trivlist doesn't set a link target by default. Use `\item[{\MakeLinkTarget[page]{}}\hskip\labelsep\textbf{#1.}]`, or (if your system is older) `\item[\phantomsection\hskip\labelsep\textbf{#1.}]`

Comment: That solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the environment **Sol** to not only produce a cross referencing label but to also create a named destination/target/anchor for linking whose name is made the new definition of the macro `\@currentHref` and thus is used by the command `\label` when creating the cross referencing label. You can use `\phantomsection`, but you can as well implement your own thing which uses the argument of the **Sol**-environment as the name for the named destination/target/anchor as well. In this case the argument of the **Sol**-environment may only consist of things which pdf-viewers can process as components of names of destinations/targets/anchors, and as no two destinations/targets/anchors may have the same name, in this case no two **Sol**-environment may have arguments that expand to the same things.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
notefont=\bfseries,
notebraces={}{}, 
headformat={\large\NUMBER.\NOTE},
headpunct={\vspace{\topsep}\newline},
spacebelow=40pt,
prefoothook={\hfill Solução: pág. \pageref{solucao:\Currentlabel}}
]{problemastyle}

\declaretheorem[style=problemastyle]{problema}

\usepackage{answers}

\Newassociation{solucao}{Sol}{solucoes}

\renewenvironment{Sol}[1]{\begin{trivlist}%
 \item[\hskip\labelsep\SolutionAnchor{#1}\textbf{#1.}]\ignorespaces}%
 {\end{trivlist}}%

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\SolutionAnchor[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \Hy@localanchornametrue
  \Hy@MakeCurrentHref{solution.#1}%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
  \label{solucao:#1}%
  \endgroup
}%
%
% Alternatively, using \phantomsection:
% 
% \DeclareRobustCommand\Hy@SolutionAnchor[1]{%
%   \begingroup
%   \Hy@localanchornametrue
%   \phantomsection
%   \label{solucao:#1}%
%   \endgroup
% }%
%
% Or, with a very recent TeX installation, use \MakeLinkTarget*
%
%\DeclareRobustCommand\SolutionAnchor[1]{%
%  \MakeLinkTarget*{solution.#1}%
%  \label{solucao:#1}%
%}%

\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{solucoes}

\begin{problema}[Primeiro problema]
 Problema 1.
 \begin{solucao}
   \lipsum
 \end{solucao}
\end{problema}

\begin{problema}[Segundo problema]
 Problema 2.
 \begin{solucao}
   \lipsum[1]
 \end{solucao}
\end{problema}

\begin{problema}[Terceiro problema]
 Problema 3.
 \begin{solucao}
   \lipsum[1]
 \end{solucao}
\end{problema}


\Closesolutionfile{solucoes}

\include{solucoes}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please no. Don't use internal and undocumented hyperref commands like \Hy@MakeCurrentHref or \Hy@raisedlink. There is no garanty that such commands will stay. There is an official interface with \MakeLinkTarget or \phantomsection.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My experience is that even documented interfaces change.And new official interfaces often did not yet make it into the package management of the operating system in use.

Comment: Sorry, but the fact that you can read the code and find the internal commands doesn't mean that you should recommend that to other users. Such tricks are bad in the long run and it makes it very hard to improve hyperref if every internal change lead to complains from users.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As long as many people don't care about update-terrorism all the time and thus don't use most recent LaTeX distros with most recent package updates, many people don't have pseudo-fancy new stuff available.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Besides this with LaTeX I gave up caring about the long run. Too many things changed.

Comment: What you do in your own documents is your own business. But if you answer a question you should also have the interest of other users in mind. And you may not care about the development, but lots of people are waiting for new stuff like tagged PDF and that requires some standarization.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the insinuations. From now on I shall be resented by your tendency to get personal. I tell you again: There are many users who do not care about the update terror but work with the TeX distribution provided by their operating system's package manager. Most of the time that is older.

Comment: sorry if I sound grumpy. But it isn't really nice to  speak of *update-terrorism*, *update terror* and *pseudo-fancy new stuff* only because I ask you in view of future development not to use internal commands but an official interface. There are really enough options  like \phantomsection (older) or \MakeLinkTarget (newer and also provided by the kernel) or  \refstepcounter or even \hypertarget.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think it is not very nice to demand everybody to have the most recent release of everything installed.I doubt that a majority of users already has a version of hyperref installed where hyperref-linktarget is incorporated. And `\phantomsection` is not a good interface for people who wish to provide names for anchors themselves. Thus I provided a solution where one can provide names of anchors oneself without the need of updating. You seem not to care about the interest of people who just want to go on with their work without the need of restructuring the whole TeX installation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer And I still take the need for doing updating often for a nuicance - each time backup so that one can roll back in case the update doesn't work... I guess when it comes to updates, I've been traumatized since Windows 95. I've also had bad experiences with system restore points from newer versions of Windows - even nowadays you can spend hours restoring a system after the update that worked fine before the update. When I did not yet work with virtual machines I used to shudder on patch day.

Comment: I didn't ask anyone to update. I mentioned a new interface and an older one and both work. But *you* are asking people not to update, as you are giving them code which will probably break in the future when the hyperref internals switch to expl3.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Imho they should not switch to expl3. Instead a package with a new name should be released.

Comment: Sorry? Why should there be a new name if only internals change?  Should I give it at every update a new name?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because internals were used in other people's code in times when "official interfaces" were not available yet so that people could not get around using internals for achieving what they needed. I suppose changing many internals without renaming packages will break compilation of many users' documents. My private packages have a component of the version number also in the package name. Package releases with the same version-number-component in the name are compatible regarding usage of internals (arguments and required amount of expansion-steps are the same...)

Comment: If someone uses or changes internals of an external package it is their job to adapt their package if these internals changes. If I change hyperref I naturally try to find breakages first and notify the authors, but nevertheless the responsability to resolve the problem lies by them. "Missing interfaces" may explain the use of the internals, but doesn't justify their use. They could have written their own package, or make a feature request for an interface instead.